# unable to apply release wise filter while fetching the task details with owner in rally

Tags: java, rally, code-rally, broadcom, rallyapi

In postman I can see results are popping correct:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task?query=(((Owner.Name = abc@google.com) and (Release.Name = PQA)) and (Project = "/project/"))&fetch=FormattedID, Actuals, Estimate, owner
```

but with java code it is returning the result of all the releases. Seems release filter is not working with the Owner name.

```
rallyRestApi = new RallyRestApi(URI.create(host), apiKey, apiKey);
QueryRequest query = new QueryRequest("task");
query.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Release.Name", "=", "XYZ"));
query.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Project", "=", "PQR"));
query.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Owner.Name", "=", "abc@google.com"));
query.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "Actuals", "Owner", "Estimates"));
query.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
query.setScopedDown(true);
QueryResponse response = rallyRestApi.query(query);
```

Comment: Try setting workspace: `query.setWorkspace("/workspace/" + workspaceId);`. Also try using `query.setProject("/project/" + projectId);` instead of setting the project as a query filter. I haven't tried these, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks jacobcs. Yes i had changed it later, and achieved my goal.